# I can't download documents from googledocs

Tags: macbook

I keep getting this message... "Sorry, we are unable to retrieve the document for viewing or you don't have permission to view the document. "

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're logged in to your google docs account when you try this. Also make sure your account has permission to view that file, otherwise, you'll get that error message. If this doesn't answer your question, then we're going to need more details from you.

Google Docs has it's [own discussion forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs?hl=en) which is ideal for this kind of question too.